# Съезжает вниз div

Tags: html, css

Имеется боковое меню и блок контента в ряд. По непонятной причине у блока контена почему-то появляется отступ сверху. Вот css:

```
.menu{
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 40px;
  background: green;
}
.page-content{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

[image]

Фон сделал для выделения блоков

Comment: Блоку, который съезжает, нужно добавить `vertical-align: top`, т.к. он `inline-block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось довольно таки просто. У `.menu` и `.page-content` я просто убрал `display: inline-block;` и в `.menu` поставил `float: left;`